# how to make a navigation bar for a mobile device

Tags: javascript, css, web, navigation

I need the code which would make a button display the navigation bar and hide it when not needed, like the one at apple.com. here is my code so far and please point out any mistakes or improvements! May i just add that this is for a mobile device!

```
.nav {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #3c8dbc 0%, #307196 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3c8dbc 0%, #307196 100%);
width:150%;
height:14%;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
list-style-type:none;
text-decoration:none;
}

.nav ul li {
list-style-type:none;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
padding:2%;
font-size:80%;
list-style-position: inside;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#63A4C9;
border:2px solid white;
width:10%;
width:60%;
top:14%;
left:0;
}

.nav a:link {
color:white;
padding:1%;
padding-left:2%;
text-decoration:none;
list-style-position: inside;
list-style-type:none;
}
.nav a:hover {
background-color:white;
color:#3c8dbc;
}
.nav a:active {
color:white;
background-color:#3c8dbc;
}
.nav a:visited {
color:white;
background-color:#3c8dbc;
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: if you're going for a mobile menu then look up hamburger menus

Comment: if you can use a framework, I'll recommend http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write some JQuery  to do so. Have a look on this example

```
.nav{display:none;} /*Add these in your CSS */
.stacked{
   position:relative;
   z-index:9999;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   color:#ccc;
   padding:5px;
   width:36px;
   background:#000
}
```

Small JQuery :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".stacked").click(function(){
    $(".mobile").toggle(100);
  });
});
```

And finally HTML

```
<div class="stacked">Menu</div>
<div class="nav mobile">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Add JQuery (if you haven't)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5237897/coderomeos          how would i make the nav bar stick to the left side becuase there is a gap :( but thank you for the code

Comment: @Jack Bradley Have you used CSS reset in your css.? If not, *{margin:0px;padding:0px} will do the same.